# Independent stochastic processes and independent random vectors

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

1. The definition for the two processes
   to be independent is given by
   [PlanetMath](https://planetmath.org/IndependentStochasticProcesses):

   > Two stochastic processes $\lbrace X(t)\mid t\in T \rbrace$ and $\lbrace Y(t)\mid t\in T \rbrace$ are said to
   > be independent, if for any positive
   > integer $n<\infty$, and any sequence
   > $t_1,\ldots,t_n\in T$, the random
   > vectors
   > $\boldsymbol{X}:=(X(t_1),\ldots,X(t_n))$
   > and
   > $\boldsymbol{Y}:=(Y(t_1),\ldots,Y(t_n))$
   > are independent.

   I was wondering if according to the
   definition, for any positive integer
   $n,m<\infty$, and any sequence
   $t_1,\ldots,t_n\in T$ and any
   sequence $s_1,\ldots,s_m\in T$, the
   random vectors
   $\boldsymbol{X}:=(X(t_1),\ldots,X(t_n))$
   and
   $\boldsymbol{Y}:=(Y(s_1),\ldots,Y(s_m))$
   are also independent?
2. Some related questions are for two
   independent random vectors $V$ and
   $W$:

   - Will any subvector of $V$ and any subvector of $W$ (the two subvectors
     do not necessarily have the same indices in the original random vectors) be independent?
   - For any two subvectors $V_1$ and    $V_2$ of $V$ and any two subvectors
     $W_1$ and $W_2$ of $W$, will the conditional random vectors $V_1|V_2$
     and $W_1|W_2$ also be independent?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer to all your questions is yes. And they can be deduced from the following :

If two random vectors $\boldsymbol{X}:=(X_1, \ldots,X_n)$ 
and $\boldsymbol{Y}:=(Y_1, \ldots,Y_m)$ are independent, any pair of "marginalized" random vectors $\boldsymbol{X_A}$,  $\boldsymbol{Y_B}$ (each formed by arbitrary subsets of the originals) are independent.

This property (basically your second question) can be readily deduced from the definition of independence (factorization of joint densities) and marginalization. From this the other two follow.

Comment: A minor problem for the third question. What if they do not have densities?

Answer (score 1):

Take $t_1, t_2, \ldots t_n, s_1,s_2, \ldots s_m \in T$ and define $X := (X(t_1), \ldots, X(s_m)), Y=(Y(t_1), \ldots , Y(s_m))$ . Now by definition $X$ and $Y$ are independent.Then take two projections $\pi_1 $ and $\pi_2$ from  $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$  to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$  and $\mathbb{R}^{m} $respectively such that $\pi_1 \circ X =(X(t_1), \ldots, X(t_n))$ and $\pi_2 \circ Y =(Y(s_1), \ldots, Y(s_m)).$ Now as projections are continuous, both $(1)$ and $(2 )$ follows.