# Proving the process $(Y_t)_{t\in[0,\infty)}$ is a standard Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $a\in(0,\infty)$. Let $(X_t)_{t\in[0,a]}$ be a standard Brownian motion and $(W_s)_{s\in[0,\infty)}$ be a standard Brownian motion such that $W_s$ is independent of $X_t$ for all $s \geqslant 0$ and $t \in [0, a]$. Define a new process $(Y_t)_{t∈[0,\infty)}$ as follows.

\begin{equation}
  Y_{t} =
    \begin{cases}
      X_t & \text{if}~0\leqslant t\leqslant a\\
      W_{t-a}+X_a & \text{if}~t>a.
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}

Justify whether the above process $(Y_t)_{t\in[0,\infty)}$ is a standard Brownian Motion.

We must check if the process $Y_t$ satisfies all the properties (independent increments, sample path continuity, etc.). To do so, you have to pick four-time points, let them be $t_j<t_{j+1}\leqslant t_i<t_{i+1}$, then vary where $a$ belongs in the in the inequality, and then take cases.

In the case where $t_j\leqslant a\leqslant t_{j+1}\leqslant t_i<t_{i+1}$ we have that $Y_{t_{j+1}}-Y_{t_{j}} = W_{t_{j+1}-a}+X_a-X_{t_{j}}$ and $Y_{t_{i+1}}-Y_{t_{i}}=W_{t_{i+1}-a}-W_{{t_i}-a}.$ How do I prove that $W_{t_{j+1}-a}$ is independent to $X_a-X_{t_{j}}$? I don't think that if $W$ is a process independent of $X$ and $Y$, then it's also necessarily independent of $X-Y$. Can someone direct me to proof of such a statement, if it exists? I would also appreciate any alternative approaches to the question.

Comment: "How do I prove that $W_{t_{j+1}-a}$ is independent to $X_a-X_{t_{j}}$?" Take the initial assumption of independence of $X$ and $W\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. I have mentioned, "I don't think that if W is a process independent of X and Y, then it's also necessarily independent of X−Y." If you think this is true, then could you direct me to proof of the same? Or, if I have misunderstood your comment, could you be more elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

*The quadratic variation of $Y$ is $t\,.$*

(The rest of the things you need to apply for Levy characterisation
I leave to you.)

*Proof.* We only have to consider partitions $0<t_1<\dots<t_n$ of the interval $[0,t]$
where $t_n=t>a\,.$ WLOG we can also assume that there is
an $t_k$ in every such partition such that $t_k=a\,.$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{i=1}^n\big(Y_{t_{i+1}}-Y_{t_i}\big)^2=\sum_{i=k+1}^n
\big(Y_{t_{i+1}}-Y_{t_i}\big)^2+\sum_{i=1}^k\big(Y_{t_{i+1}}-Y_{t_i}\big)^2\\[2mm]
&=\sum_{i=k+1}^n
\big(W_{t_{i+1}-a}-X_a-W_{t_i-a} +X_a\big)^2+\sum_{i=1}^k\big(X_{t_{i+1}}-X_{t_i}\big)^2\,.
\end{align}
The limit of the second term is $a\,.$ The first term is
\begin{align}
&\sum_{i=k+1}^n
\big(W_{t_{i+1}-a}-W_{t_i-a}\big)^2\\
\end{align}
whose  limit is $t-a\,.$

Answer (score 0):

First, lets clarify what **independent processes** means [Independent stochastic processes and independent random vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22360/independent-stochastic-processes-and-independent-random-vectors). The definition for the two processes
to be independent is given by
[PlanetMath](https://planetmath.org/IndependentStochasticProcesses):

> Two stochastic processes $\lbrace X(t)\mid t\in T \rbrace$ and $\lbrace Y(t)\mid t\in T \rbrace$ are said to
> > be independent, if for any positive
> > integer $n<\infty$, and any sequence
> > $t_1,\ldots,t_n\in T$, the random
> > vectors
> > $\boldsymbol{X}:=(X(t_1),\ldots,X(t_n))$
> > and
> > $\boldsymbol{Y}:=(Y(t_1),\ldots,Y(t_n))$
> > are independent.

So in this particular, we have independence of the vectors

$$(W_{t_{1}},...,W_{t_{n}})\text{ and }(X_{s_{1}},...,X_{s_{n}})$$

and so this also implies $W_{t_{2}}-W_{t_{1}}$ is independent of $X_{s_{2}}-X_{s_{1}}$.

The rest of the proof follows as the above answer mentioned https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4882724/383044.